# Glitch with Yamato Cannons?

Tags: starcraft-2

I notice when I select a group of battle cruisers in Starcraft 2, and choose the Yamato Cannon action, only one of them fires it. I remember in Starcraft 1, the entire group would fire YC. Is this a glitch? I have the OSX version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is intended and is referred  to as "Smart Casting", and it makes it easier to micro manage your units. In Starcraft 1, you would often over cast your spells. For example, if you had a selected group of High Templar and you casted psionic storm, every single one of your templar would cast psionic storm in the same spot, which is a waste of energy.

It's much more efficient to just press the hot-key of the unit's spell.

As a note, be careful about holding shift before casting any spell. If the unit is doing anything before you queue the spell, the unit will not cast the spell until the previous action is done.

For example, your BCs are sitting there, and then a swarm of mutas attack you. You press and hold shift to queue up yamato cannons, but wait! your BCs started auto-attacking before you could give the yamato cannon command. Now they completly ignore the yamato cannon order until all mutas are dead. This same problem exists for all other spell casting units.

Comment: Is there a way to tell the other BC's to fire their cannon? IIRC, you can't tab between BC's - is there any way other than manually selecting each one?

Comment: Yes. 1) Select all your BCs, 2) Press the Yamato cannon hotkey ('Y' I think), 3) click on the enemy target. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until all BCs have fired. This is much easier if you hold the "shift" button down, but you will probably run into the issue I mentioned above. Better to not hold shift and just press the button over and over again.

Comment: thanks. I guess it makes sense. The only time I do a group action is to use multiple BCs to take down a base or mothership. I find a burst of combined YC is more effective. I'll have to get used to the clicking...

Comment: @RodYan That won't work. You still have to wait for the current firing event to finish, before the Yamato Spell is available again. To make others fire, select them separately and choose Yamato again.